# A hard-looking integral that's seemingly easy: $\int_{-100}^{+100}\int_{-100}^{+100}(2y+1)e^{2y\ln(x)}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

So I was bored, and decided to evaluate some integrals. After a while, I came up with this:$$\int_{-100}^{+100}\int_{-100}^{+100}(2y+1)e^{2y\ln(x)}dxdy$$which I thought that I might be able to evaluate. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\int_{-100}^{+100}\int_{-100}^{+100}(2y+1)e^{2y\ln(x)}dxdy\implies\int_{-100}^{+100}\int_{-100}^{+100}(2y+1)x^{2y}dxdy$$$$\implies\left.\dfrac{x^{2y+1}}{\require{cancel}\cancel{2y+1}}\right]_{-100}^{+100}\cancel{(2y+1)}\implies100\int_{-100}^{+100}10000^y+10000^ydy$$$$=100\int_{-100}^{+100}20000^ydy\implies100\left[\dfrac{20000^y}{\ln(20000)}\right]_{-100}^{+100}=100\left(\dfrac{20000^{200}-1}{20000^{100}\ln(20000)}\right)$$$$=\dfrac{4^{100}100^{401}-100}{20000^{100}\ln(20000)}$$$$\approx1.28000423437055155\cdot10^{431}$$as seen by [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5BPower%5B4%2C100%5DPower%5B100%2C401%5D-100%2CPower%5B20000%2C100%5Dln%5C%2840%2920000%5C%2841%29%5D) result by Wolfram Alpha, so this is the result from the evaluation is as seen above.

---

#### My question

---

Is my evaluation of the integral correct, or what could I do to evaluate it/evaluate it more quickly?

Comment: I actually forgot to put in the beginning (had it copied to my clipboard, will fix that right now)

Comment: You integrate $\ln x$ over  $-100\le x\le 0\,.$ I recommend to choose more sensical integration limits.

Comment: @KurtG. While I do agree with what you mean by this, I feel like I should note that right away, $x$ can be moved down to become $x^{2y}$ because the $\ln(x)$ and $e$ cancel eachother out right away (although I do see why that might be a problem since $e^{\ln(x)}$ technically only simplifies to $x$ for $x\in\mathbb R^+$, if we were to go for a more standard definition for $e$ to the power of a natural logarithm.)

Comment: How do you define $x^y$ for negative $x$ and $y$ not an integer? Messing around with notation won't work wonders.

Comment: The second implication is wrong since $\int x^{2 y} d x=\frac{x^{2 y+1}}{2 y+1} +C \quad$ if $y \neq-\frac{1}{2}$